# Symfony2: Entity with a relation to a unique entity

Tags: xml, symfony, doctrine-orm, unique, jmsserializerbundle

### Starting point

I write a small Application to collect some hardware data of the machines in my network. I have written a collector powershell script which sends me an XML request with the data to my Symfony2 Application.

My entity architecture:
I have a `composition` which has a relation to the `cpu`, `printer` and other components entities. So a `composition`has only references to other entities, except the id field. This architecture is given.

### Problem

It may be that multiple machines have the same `cpu`. I don't want to fill up the cpu table so i decided to make `cpu` an [Unique Entity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html). It works, so when i want so add an entity with the same fields twice it throws an exception. 
But here starts my problem. I deserialize the XML into the `composition` object with the [JMSSerializerBundle](http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle). It also creates the `cpu` object and makes the relation between. When i then persist the `composition`entity, it gets me the exception because the cpu already exists. So i have to redefine the relation to the cpu which already exists before i persist the `composition` entity.

### Solutions

At this point i see only two dirty solutions:

- I check the `composition` object before persisting it. There i search in the database if a same entity already exists and then referencing to it.
- I catch the exception and get the existing entity from the database for referencing to it.

I am very glad about further solutions!

Comment: Maybe the first time you send store a composition, you should send back the id of the composition to the script(you store it on a file to have access to it ever after restarting) then the script will send new requests to a new path like /composition/{id}, so you already know which composition it is about.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but thats not the way i want to make it. I don't want to but some logic into the collector script. It should just POST the xml data to my server application where the logic is implemented.

Comment: Okay so, search for a similar "composition" before saving, if a composition like that exists you link to it if not you save a new(it actually what MySQL does before throwing the exception)

Comment: Yes, i already do that, i make a hash of the xml and i made a little caching for that. But the point is, if the composition is NOT the same and a component of it (like cpu) is already existing then i have to create a new composition, but not a new cpu. I have to link the existing cpu with the new composition.

Comment: Search the cpu, and use that object on the composition. i may understand you. but i don't see any issue for now. you should maybe show your database schema and your xml. because i don't what is the issue.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thats the first solution i see. For me its a little bit dirty to do that by myself, i thought symfony mabye gets me a service for that. I think i will do it like that:
In will make an EventListener on the prePersist Event, and a custom repository for my component entities, which got the function findBySameProperties (or something like that).
On the event listener i check this method. But it would be nice to mark the properies of an entity via annotations, so all annotated properties would be checked by the method. I think that should be possible.